# Context flow and entity not working in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using actions on google and dialogflow to build an open ended conversation app. I have created an entity named 'Rating' and it is used to store numbers from 1 to 5, below is the screenshot of the entity:

[image]

I am using this entity in an intent named 'First'. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

The very first intent which I am using is 'Survey ID'. Below is the code for the survey ID intent:

```
app.intent('Survey ID', (conv, {number}) => {
    const id = number;
    if(id == 2020){
        conv.ask(qstion[0]);
    }
    else{
        conv.close('This is not a valid survey ID');
    }
});
```

Following is the code for the 'First' intent:

```
app.intent('First', (conv) => {
    const rating = conv.parameters.Rating;
    if(type[0] === 'RATING'){
        if(rating >= 1 && rating <= 5){
            senddata[0] =  qstion[0] + rating;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else{
            conv.ask('Please enter a number between 1 and 5');
        }
    }

});
```

I am also using a fallback intent for the 'First' intent. Following is the code for the fallback intent:

```
app.intent('First - fallback', (conv) => {
    const userSaid = conv.query;
    conv.close(userSaid);
});
```

The issue I am facing is that even though I am entering a number between 1 to 5 it is going inside the else block in the 'First' intent's code and saying 'Please enter a number between 1 and 5'. And when I am using any number other than 1 to 5 it should go to the fallback intent but it goes to the 'Survey ID' intent and says 'This is not a valid survey ID'.

The intended behavior is that if I enter a number between 1 and 5 it should store it and ask the next question and if I say anything else it should go to the fallback intent and display the user's response.

For reference I am also giving the contexts of all the three intents:

'Survey ID' context:

[image]

'First' context:

[image]

'First-fallback' context:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: If you were to look at the JSON request, my guess is that the value of rating is not a `number` but a `string`. You may need to first convert the value using `parseInt(conv.parameters.Rating)`

Comment: @NickFelker I tried this, but it's not working

Comment: What's the value of 'Rating'?

Comment: If I enter 5, the rating value is "five"

Comment: I changed the rating entity, instead of "one" I used 1,so it's working fine if I enter any number between 1 and 5 but if I enter 9 it doesn't go into the fallback intent and still says "This is not  a valid survey ID"